# How to find files (files only) with the ending 'y' and '.txt' in the current directory and move them to a different folder?

Tags: linux, unix

I used:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*y" | mv {} /Downloads/
```

But it did not do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try following command.

mv *y.txt destinationFolderPath

I hope it helps!!!